# Is this term correct?

Tags: adjectives

I wonder  if this sentence "I m the most recent fan here" is correct? I mean if the word "recent" can describe a person?

Comment: I don't think this question could be answered without more context.  Recent in regards to what event?

Comment: I think it works but it's not very optimal. I think something along the lines of "I am the latest fan here" would be better. Or if this is a fanclub, you might say, "I am the newest member of the fanclub".

Comment: I mean someone who listens to this band   for a short time compared to the rest of people in forum.

Answer (score 1):

**"the most recent"** can refer to people.

> - This is John, the most recent acquision to our department.
> - Christiano Ronaldo is the most recent acquisition to our team.

In your sentence, however, it would sound better to say **"I'm the newest fan here"**.

Comment: I mean someone who listens to this band for a short time compared to the rest of people in forum. In such a case, it will be sounded good?

Comment: In your sentence i would stick to "newest".

Answer (score 0):

"Recent" is defined by American Heritage as "Of, belonging to, or occurring at a time immediately before the present." Webster's concurs. Thus, "recent events," "recent developments," etc. In this case, you are attempting to communicate that you are currently a fan and that, among those in the room, it is you who has most recently *become* a fan--this makes you the *newest* fan here, which describes your current situation.